# www-data User Cannot Send Mail

Tags: linux, ubuntu-16.04, sendmail

I am setting up a web based CRM on a clients server which only has a root user set up on it. We are finding that they are unable to send mails from the CRM.

I tested sending mails from the command line using the www-data account, and while `sudo -u www-data sh -c 'sendmail crmtestuser@mailinator.com < /tmp/email.txt'` works successfully, and a mail is sent and received successfully, when I try `sudo -u www-data sh -c 'mail -s "My Test Subject" crmtestuser@mailinator.com< /tmp/email.txt'`, I get:

```
mail: cannot stat `/root/.mail': Permission denied
mail: Cannot open `/root/.mailrc': Permission denied
```

When I `ls -l /var/mail`, there is only one entry:

```
-rw------- 1 root mail 6223 Mar  5 15:19 root
```

There are no error messages in /var/log/mail.err or /var/log/apache2/error.log from the attempts to send mails from either the mail command on the command line nor attempts to send mails through the CRM.

Any ideas for what I could try?

Answer (score 0):

It still assumes that you are 'root'.  Add the -i option to sudo to simulate a login, then the username in the environment will match the targetet user.